# To handle multiple schemas in one DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using an existing Database with a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 application. The database has two schemas, dbo and notinapplication. I do not want to create model of notinapplication schema tables. So I use the following code in Package manager and it works fine.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost; Database=TestServer; Trusted_Connection=True; 
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
-UseDatabaseNames -Force -Context "DbContext" -Schema "dbo"
```

This way I only get tables from dbo in DbContext and the notinapplication schema tables are ignored.

However now I have a new schema called user that needs to be part of the model.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost; Database=TestServer; Trusted_Connection=True; 
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
-UseDatabaseNames -Force -Context "DbContext" -Schema "user"
```

But using the above code eliminates the tables from dbo schema. What are my options to have tables of both schemas in DBContext while ignoring the notinapplication schema.

And if I indeed have to create different contexts, is it possible to query from multiple DB contexts in one query?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All you need to do to provide multiple values is to use the 'array syntax'.

```
-Schema "schema1","schema2","schema3"
```

In your case, you have to do

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost; Database=TestServer; Trusted_Connection=True; 
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
-UseDatabaseNames -Force -Context "DbContext" -Schema "dbo","user"
```

Comment: is there any way to have one context with different schemas in the different location?

Comment: After migration to **dotnet-ef v.6** I had to replace `--schema "schema1","schema2"` by `--schema "schema1" --schema "schema2"` (previous version worked fine with dotnet-ef v.5)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the [job](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/4958d11c84f3a4999ecf8aa65b3f036e6cd0ca7f/src/EFCore.Relational/Scaffolding/DatabaseModelFactoryOptions.cs) by using `-Schema` parameter multiple times in this way though :/

```
 -Schema "dbo" -Schema "user"
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I got "Scaffold-DbContext : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Schemas' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3". error

Comment: yea i see, changing it to array syntax will work like `-Schema "value1" ,"value2", "value3"`